# HTTPS redirect in htaccess only when a query parameter is not equal to something

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4

**Background**

I've managed to get http to https redirection working for my Wordpress installation by including this snippet in my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I'm running in the Google Cloud environment and the problem is that the health check requires that the "health checked resource" returns `200 OK`. The health check issues an HTTP request without the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header set so Apache will respond with a `301` and thus the health check fails (it doesn't follow redirects). Unfortunately it's not possible to define headers in the Google Health Checker so I can't fake the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to "https". So my hope for a workaround would be to supply a query parameter in the health check path and configure the `.htaccess` file to ONLY redirect if the specified query param is undefined (or equal to false or something similar).

**Question**

How can I modify the `RewriteCond` (I presume) to only perform redirection if the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header is not equal `https` (as in the example above) *AND* the query string does not contain the parameter `healthCheck=true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try with this?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*healthCheck=true.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824964/rewritecond-in-htaccess-with-negated-regex-condition-doesnt-work and https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString .

Comment: This works but note that the ".htaccess file" I presented in my question was slightly wrong (I've now edited it). The "RewriteRule" should look like this: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: Corrected answer with new RewriteRule.